# X-Pack 401 Logstash cant connect to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, http-status-code-401, elk

I changed JVM heap sized and Logstash cant connect to Elasticsearch, after restarting Elasticsearch

logstash.yml

```
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["es:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: pass
```

---

logs by Logstash

> [WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://es:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://es:9200/'"}

---

curl from logstash to es with same credentials

```
logstash: curl -ulogstash_system es:9200
Enter host password for user 'logstash_system':
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "",
    "build_date" : "2019-11-26T01:06:52.518245Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: The Logstash configuration you've posted focusses on xpack monitoring. I think that the error message is coming from a pipeline that uses an elasticsearch output plugin. Do you have such a pipeline running? If yes, please update your question with the pipeline configuration.

Comment: pipeline.yml
`- pipeline.id: beats
  path.config: "{{ ls_conf_dir }}/beats.conf"
- pipeline.id: rsyslog
  path.config: "{{ ls_conf_dir }}/rsyslog.conf"`
configs without creds

Comment: This is just the declaration in pipelines.yml. We need the actual implementation (the .conf files). And as I asked you before **please add the code to your original question with proper indentations...**